# How to pass parameters to a JQuery $.getJSON callback method?

Tags: javascript, json

```
 function CallMethod() {
     $.getJSON('/website/RESTfulService.svc/LiveLocation/json?{x=1,y=2}', function(data) {
         getResult(data.lat, data.lon);
     });
 }
```

Comment: try '/website/RESTfulService.svc/LiveLocation/json?x=1&y=2'

Answer (score 92):

Pass them as an object just after the URL and before the function:

```
function CallMethod() {
     $.getJSON('/website/RESTfulService.svc/LiveLocation/json', 
     {
        x: "1",
        y: "2"
     }, 
     function(data) {
         getResult(data.lat, data.lon);
     });
}
```

Comment: I had no idea this is possible, just great.

Comment: How about passing no parameter/void? should I do `$.getJSON('/website/RESTfulService.svc/LiveLocation/json',null,function(data){...});`?

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, first create javascript object for the sake of simplicity and then pass

```
var myObject = {x: "1", y: "2"};

$.getJSON('/website/RESTfulService.svc/LiveLocation/json', myObject, function(dataVal) {
    //Use Your result
});
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer as Zheileman's, and it is not easy to read.

Comment: I know this is the same answer but  the way of passing your data as a parameter is different. I have already mentioned that It is for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I see your point. I have submitted a suggested edit of your answer which is more readable (which is the purpose of this alternative solution)

Answer (score 4):

Just like Zheileman said, but note that this way, although you passed the parameters in JSON format, the actual  parameters are passed to the webserver as an Encoded HTTP URL which will end up this way:

**/website/RESTfulService.svc/LiveLocation/json?x=1&y=2**