# How to submit a form and pass some extra parameters to a $.getJSON callback method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know how to pass some parameters to a JQuery $.getJSON callback method, [thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570562/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-jquery-getjson-callback-method):

```
$.getJSON('/website/json',
{
  action: "read",
  record: "1"
}, 
function(data) {
   // do something
});
```

And I can also submit a form to a $.getJSON callback method:

```
$.getJSON('/website/json', $(formName)
function(data) {
   // do something
});
```

But I want to pass some parameters AND submit some form elements. How can I combine the two things togheter?

I could serialize the form elements and manually add some parameters to the url, and it looks like it works:

```
$.getJSON('/website/json',
  'action=read&record=1&'
  + $(formName).serialize(),
function(data) {
   // do something
});
```

But it doesn't look very elegant. Is this the proper way, or there's a better way to do it?

Comment: You can pass them like: `$.getJSON('/website/json', { action: "read", record: 1, .. }` - not sure what else ya can do.

Comment: why not just have the parameters you want to pass be part of the form element, perhaps as hidden input elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could implement the functionality [demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403206/2039244) as a custom jQuery instance method which produces an object of key/value pairs from a form and combines it with the properties that aren't derived from the form:

```
$.fn.formObject = function (obj) {
    obj = obj || {};
    $.each(this.serializeArray(), function (_, kv) {
        obj[kv.name] = kv.value;
    });
    return obj;
};

$.getJSON('/website/json', $(formName).formObject({
    action: "read",
    record: "1"
}), function(data) {
   // do something
});
```

Comment: I had to add a `return obj;` after `$.each` and it works. Interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

Make an Ajax post to send the data to the server. Retrieve the parameter data in the backend code along with the form data.

```
var formData = {data from form};

formData.action = 'read';
formData.post = '1';

$.ajax({
  url: '/website/json',
  type: "post",
  data: formData
}).done(function (data) {
    // remove prior values set upon request response

    formData.action = null;
    formData.post = null;
});
```

Comment: What is `{data from form}`? That isn't legal JavaScript.

Comment: @sdgluck it's like a placeholder, "put here the selector you want", I'm going to test both answers soon and I'll give you feedback.. thanks :)

Comment: @deek I like this approach, but I cannot make it work. The ajax post is fine, but "action" and "post" don't seem to be sent to the server. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @fthiella how are you calling the data? data.action? Try data.formData.action. Alternatively, the ajax request finished before the new properties were added. You could use a promise to set those values(or Jquery's ajax beforeSend). Does action and post return a null value or come back as undefined?