# Unable to pass html button to Flask

Tags: python, flask

Colleagues,

I have my index.html page with just two buttons and want to pass to Flask which one was pressed.
I do see the GET message passing to the server the id, I am not beign able to get in flask/python

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="/static/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<body>

<button type="button" id="ade" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Adelante</button>
<button type="button" id="atr" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Atras</button>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(clicked_id)
{

    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{request.script_root|tojson|safe}};
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/',
    clicked_id, function(data)
             {
                    var response = data.result;
                    console.log(response);
            }
            );

}
</script>

</html>
```

on Flask I have

```
@app.route('/')
def indice():
    clicked_id = request.args.get('clicked_id')
    print clicked_id
```

Everytime i press the buttons I do get the id of the button, but in python I get None (on the print)

```
None
192.168.1.13 - - [07/Sep/2016 01:14:56] "GET /?atr HTTP/1.1" 200 -
None
192.168.1.13 - - [07/Sep/2016 01:15:02] "GET /?ade HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: you have to send `?clicked_id=atr`, `?clicked_id=ade`

Comment: passing `{clicked_id: clicked_id}` to as the optional data parameter would work right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570562/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-jquery-getjson-callback-method

Comment: SuperShoot was right. Just added {clicked_id: clicked_id} and that fixed my code. Thank you!!!!